# How can I report the default bin width in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

This is the line that I used to draw a histogram using the `ggplot2` package,

```
ggplot(ex0116, aes(PerCapitaGDP)) +geom_histogram(fill=NA, color="black") + theme_bw()
```

When I activate it, it shows a desired histogram and the message that says

> 'stat_bin()' using 'bins=30'.Pick better value with 'binwidth'

appears.

So I guess that I have a total of 30 bins, but what I want to do is **to get the default bin width of this histogram**, not the number of bins. I know how to change the bin width, but don't know how to get the default bin width.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: [There is no default binwidth](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html), it is calculated from the 30 bins.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you would be:

```
diff(range(ex0116$PerCapitaGDP))/30
```

This is the way `ggplot2` calculates the bin width.

Hope it helps!